How do I return multiple result sets in Dapper from a stored procedure
I am having problems with Dapper when using QueryMultipleAsync closing the reader before I have fetched all of the result sets.
I am able to grab the maxpage but anytime I try and grab the actual data which looks something like below, it will fail with a System.ObjectDisposedException: The reader has been disposed; this can happen after all data has been consumed Object name: 'Dapper.SqlMapper+GridReader'.



MaxPage




54






ID
First_Name
Last_Name




1352
Bob
Jackson


1234
Joe
Jim



public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryMultipleAsync<T, U>(string storedProcedure,
            U parameters,
            string connectionStringName = "Default")
{
            string? connectionString = _config.GetCfonnectionString(connectionStringName);
            using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            var results = await connection.QueryMultipleAsync(storedProcedure,
                parameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            var maxpage = await results.ReadFirstAsync();
            var values = await results.ReadAsync<T>();
            return (values);
}


The problem is that you are reading from the database asynchronously and returning the results as a Task<IEnumerable<T>> to the caller. Your database connection gets disposed when the scope of its using ends (at the return statement). However, the database is only accessed when that enumerable is realized (say, by a call to ToList). You'll need to either realize the list before your return or return the connection to the caller (the caller must dispose it in this case). In a previous lifetime I had a disposable generic WrappedReader that I used to do this.

The interesting thing is that it's disposing it well before the return. I set breakpoints and ran through it line by line and it throws an exception as soon as it hits the line to read the values columns.

To add onto this, I did try and realize the enumerable before it returned but it failed before it got there. I can't thank you enough for your answer however.

Life is complicated in async-land and disposable connections. As a test, get rid of the using (just create to connection) then return the enumerable and the connection back to the caller. Once the caller is finished, dispose the connection. Then figure out how to wrap it all up. Having two result sets is going to complicate things even more. But step one is to stop disposing at the scope you are doing it now

Perhaps you aren't actually returning two resultsets? What does the procedure actually do? @Flydog57 Pretty sure Dapper by default buffers into a list, so does not throw in this situation.

https://imgur.com/a/4p8Wv06 That is the output from the stored procedure.

Alright, in case anyone has this in the future, I have figured it out. I was using everything correctly but I had a user search model that was being used to fill out the parameters. There was an additional parameter I forgot I added in there and when that was passed to the stored procedure, it would null out the results. This caused dapper to close the connection after the first result grid because there were in fact no more results. Thank you all for trying to assist.
